# CPUTIME and WALLTIME C++ code on Linux based cluster

Tags: c++, linux, bash, cpu-time, wall-time

I have a C++ code that i'm running a linux based cluster. I want to measure the CPU time and wall time. Here is how the bash file for submitting the job looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -V
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y 
#$ -orte_onenode 2 
#$ -o out
#$ -N program
~/home/directory/executable
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What if you replace `~/home/directory/executable` with `time ~/home/directory/executable`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. But not sure how to read the output. Here is what i got:145.58u 9.072s 2:36.27 98.9 0+0k 392+340672io 1pf+0w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `~/home/directory/executable` with `time ~/home/directory/executable` in your script.  This runs the "time" program, which as you noted in a comment prints something like:

```
145.58u 9.072s 2:36.27 98.9 0+0k 392+340672io 1pf+0w
```

The first number there is the user-mode time (in seconds).  The second is system (kernel) mode time.  Third is the total elapsed wall time (minutes:seconds).  `98.9` is the CPU utilization during the run.  You can read more about these values and the `time` program here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/time